# What does (cons? list-name) do?

Tags: list, scheme, short, cons

I was wondering what `(cons? list-name)` does. Does it just check that `list-name` is not a non-empty list? Is it just like the opposite of `(empty? list-name)`? If so, then is it not better to just say `(empty? list-name)` and then say `else` instead of `cons?`? For example:

```
(define (f list-name)
   (cond
     [(empty? list-name) empty]
     [(cons? list-name) "do something]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`cons?` checks whether the value is a `cons` cell, e.g., something that's `(cons foo bar)` for some `foo` and `bar`.

```
> (cons? 1)
#f
> (cons? '())
#f
> (cons? (list 1 2 3))
#t
> (cons? (cons 1 2))
#t
```

If `(cons? a)` is true, then it is safe to use `car` and `cdr` on `a`.

This isn't the opposite of `empty?` since `empty?` is true if and only if the argument is the empty list, so `(empty? 1) == (cons? 1) == #f`.

Sidenote: Please don't put `PLEASE HELP!!` or similar in your question titles, everyone here is happy to help, but it's a bit obnoxious to read. Just something to keep in mind in the future. Welcome to SO.

Comment: This is correct.  _However_, if the argument coming in is known to be a list (whether by previous checks, or because that's what the function requires), then it _does_ make sense to have a simple if/else.  `empty?` checks whether you've got the trivial case of a list, and _everything else_ should be a list on which you can use `first` and `rest`.

Answer (score 1):

[jozefg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20335654/1281433) is right in pointing out that `(cons? x)` is not the same as `(not (empty? x))`, in general, because there are things (e.g., numbers) that are neither cons cells nor the empty list.

However, your variable was `list-name`, so you may have some reason to expect that its value is, in fact a list.  A list, in Scheme, is either:

- the empty list; or
- a cons cell whose `car` is the `first` element of a list and whose `cdr` is the `rest` of the list.

Because of this, if you're writing a function that requires a list be passed in, then it *does* make sense to simply check for the trivial case (the empty list) with `empty?`, and to assume, since you've required a list, that anything that doesn't match that case is a cons cell on which you can call `cdr` and `cdr`.  This is because while

```
(cons? x) == (not (empty? x))
```

is not true of values in general, it *is* true for lists.  That is, if you already know that `lst` is a list, then

```
(cons? lst) == (not (empty? lst))
```

is *true*.  There are a number of functions that do the same thing when we're talking about lists and cons cells.  E.g., `empty?` and `null?` do the same thing, but they signal a slightly different intent on the part of the programmer.  Similarly, `car` and `cdr` do the same thing as `first` and `rest`, but `car` and `cdr` signal that you might be treating something as a pair of two things, whereas `first` and `rest` clearly signal the intent that you're working with a list.

Your code, since it seems to expect a list, should probably be the following, since, for a list, if it's not the empty list, it must be a cons.

```
(define (f lst)
   (cond
     [(empty? lst) empty]
     [else "do something]))
```

More generally, the code you write should depend on what kind of input you expect.  E.g., in the first case, it's fine to check for empty, and assume a cons otherwise, because you're expecting a list.  In the second case, you have to check for all the different kinds of things you might see.

```
(define (frob-list lst)
   (cond
     [(empty? lst) empty]  ; arg is ()
     [else ...]))          ; arg is (x . y)

(define (frob-object obj)
   (cond
     [(null? obj) ...]     ; arg is ()
     [(cons? obj) ...]     ; arg is (x . y)
     [(number? obj) ...]   ; arg is r
     ...                   ; arg is ...
     [else ...]))          ; else ...
```

Comment: IOW, rely on the function's contract for the simplified code's correctness.  :)